# Is there a GNU coreutils function like sort but just finds the maximum or minimum value?

Tags: sorting, gnu-coreutils

I was looking for a function that behaves just like the `sort` function in GNU coreutils (in terms of the arguments it takes in) except that it just finds the maximum or minimum. In my particular case, I can do fine with `sort`, but I was wondering what I would have to do if I was in a position where the extra log(n) work was unnecessary e.g. finding the maximum of say a billion random things repeatedly (each instance with a different billion random things, and repeatedly could mean a billion times or more, and things could be integers or whatever else `sort` supports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not such functionality but it is on the list of things to do for GNU coreutils. I.E. we'll add a new option to sort(1) to support this